# Using math in loaded module in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

in my main python file I just load the math module and an own module (called funcs.py). Finally, I run a function from the just loaded module.

```
import math
from funcs import *

RetentionTime(1,2,3,4)
```

The funcs.py file looks like this:

```
def RetentionTime(a, b, c, d):
"calculation of retention time"
RT = (11.2 * a) / (b * c * math.degrees( math.atan( d / 100 ) ) )

return RT
```

This leads to the following Nameerror:

> NameError: name 'math' is not defined

In the python shell I can use commands like math.atan(...) without a problem. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Add import math to funcs.py

Comment: and remove import math from your main

Comment: For overview purposes I put constants I use in a separate file (consts.py) and functions, also (funcs.py). I want to work in the main file and maybe also use math functions here. Isn't it possible to only import math module once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# test.py
y = 5
def f(x):
    print(x+y)
```

Here `f` will bind the object named `y` from the innermost scope, which in this case is the module scope of `test.py`. Had it been as follows,

```
y = 5
def g():
    y = 10
    def f(x):
        print(x+y)
    return f
```

Here the `y` bound in `f` will be object `10`. In your case `RetentionTime` is compiled in its own module scope and has no access to the scope of the caller. Hence add `import math` to the same module as `RetentionTime`.